# Why is the return type IdentityUser and not ApplicationUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have this class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
   public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

and in **DbContext** class this is what I've done

```
public partial class PickerDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public PickerDbContext():base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    }
    //public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

now when I try to query the `Users` table in my repository with something like

```
var user = _db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u=>u.anyfield);
```

I think it has return type as `IdentityUser` and not `ApplicationUser` because when I do `u=>u.` intellisense option doesn't show the fields from `ApplicationUser`

[image]

What should I do to make the querying in `Users` table return `ApplicationUser` type and why is it giving me return type as `IdentityUser`

Comment: did you try `_dbContext.Users.OfType<ApplicationUser>().SingleOrDefault...`

Comment: nope, will give it a shot. Just a minute

Comment: Another guess, since using `.OfType` is not the way its supposed to be. (I don't need to do that) - try deleting `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");` since you already map ApplicationUser to that table. My suspicion is, that the second line overwrites the first line, somehow and thats why that entity returns `IdentityUser` instead of `ApplicationUser`. Give it a try please.

Comment: @Serv ok will give it a shot

Comment: @Serv no it doesn't work if i remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because IdentityDbContext is not a class you defined, and ApplicationUser is a class that you did define. You create ApplicationUser that inherits from IdentityUser. You create a context that inherits from IdentityDbContext. IdentityDbContext exposes DbSet.

If you want the data to come back as ApplicationUser you can do the following:

```
context.Users.OfType<ApplicationUser>();
```

You may also be able to do this in your custom DbContext (unverified):

```
public new DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
```

I haven't tested that though.